# Don't let Bootstrap "row" content to jump in the new line

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This is how my website looks like in desktop view,

[image]

And this is how it looks in mobile view,

[image]

The `Tags` looks perfect in Desktop view but in mobile view it is not able to fit all in a single line. That's why, it is jumping to the new line. The tags `#pytorch` and `#tensorflow` is in the new line. I want to avoid this behavior. If it is not able to accommodate all in a single line just hide the the rest of all the `Tags` in the new line (which means to hide `#pytorch` and `#tensorflow`).

Minimum Reproducible code:

```css
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@430&display=swap');

        .main {
            max-width: 1200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .read-more p a span:hover {
            color: #0085a1;
        }

        .title-text:hover {
            color: #337ab7;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .title-text {
            font-family: 'Lato';
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: #404040;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .tag p span:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            border-radius: 4px;
        }

        .date {
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #707070;
            margin-left: 15px;
            font-family: 'Work Sans';
        }

        .read {
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #707070;
            margin-left: 7px;
            font-family: 'Work Sans';
        }

        .author {
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #707070;
            margin-left: 7px;
            font-family: 'Work Sans';
        }

        .desc p {
            font-size: 17px;
            font-family: 'Work Sans'
        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3e34c14145.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="main" style="padding-top: 3%; padding-bottom: 5%;">
        <div class="blog-card">
            <div class="row" style="background-color: #fff; padding-top: 1%;">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="https://mlthon.pythonanywhere.com/media/guides/img/carbon_2.png"
                        style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; border-radius: 7px; padding-bottom: 3%;">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <a href="/article/Loading-Really-Large-Datasets-Efficiently-With-Generators-Pytorch-and-TensorFlow"
                        style="text-decoration: none;">
                        <h1 class="title-text">Loading Really Large Datasets Efficiently With Generators (Pytorch &amp;
                            TensorFlow)</h1>
                    </a>

                    <div class="post-meta" style="text-align: center;">
                        <div class="row">
                            <p class="date">&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-calendar-week" aria-hidden="true"></i> Posted On
                                May 5, 2022&nbsp;|</p>
                            <p class="read">&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-clock" aria-hidden="true"></i><span
                                    class="span_read">&nbsp;10 minutes</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="desc">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo sunt tempora dolor laudantium
                            sed optio, explicabo ad deleniti impedit facilis fugit recusandae! Illo, aliquid, dicta
                            beatae quia porro id est.</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="read-more" style="float: right;">
                        <p style="font-family: 'Open Sans'; font-weight: 700; font-size: 18px;"><a
                                href="/article/Loading-Really-Large-Datasets-Efficiently-With-Generators-Pytorch-and-TensorFlow"
                                style="text-decoration: none; color: black;"><span>[Read
                                    More]</span></a></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 1px; overflow: hidden;">
                        <p style="font-family: 'Open Sans'; font-size: 1rem">Tags:</p>

                        <!-- THIS IS WHERE PROBLEM STARTS -->

                        <div class="tag">
                            <p style="font-family: 'Dosis'; font-size: 1rem; color: #008AFF; cursor: pointer;"
                                onclick="tag('deep-learning')">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>#deep-learning</span></p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tag">
                            <p style="font-family: 'Dosis'; font-size: 1rem; color: #008AFF; cursor: pointer;"
                                onclick="tag('data')">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>#data</span></p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tag">
                            <p style="font-family: 'Dosis'; font-size: 1rem; color: #008AFF; cursor: pointer;"
                                onclick="tag('pytorch')">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>#pytorch</span></p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tag">
                            <p style="font-family: 'Dosis'; font-size: 1rem; color: #008AFF; cursor: pointer;"
                                onclick="tag('tensorflow')">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>#tensorflow</span></p>
                        </div>


                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, the div has very short width so the `Sample 3` and `Sample 4` has automatically came down. I want to avoid this behavior and want to hide `Sample 3` and `Sample 4`. So, the desired output should looks like this:

[image]

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The [Readmore] is blocking the tag. You could try and push the tags down with a mediaquery?

Comment: Please add an [example]

Comment: @Kameron Sure. I will add it.

Comment: I have added the minimal reproducible example @Kameron. Take a look!

Comment: @PritishMishra like this? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/6hy7rstv/1/)

Comment: @PritishMishra post your actual code that recreates the screenshot with the tags. I don't want to guess at other styles.

Comment: @Kameron https://jsfiddle.net/w2a361rm/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

The problem is that the readme block has a float right outside the row, while the row itself has no width. You can add an `col-md-12` class within the row to force a full width tag list, but that will push the read more outside.

While I would go for a manually written CSS Flexbox based solution for this problem, with bootstrap you can do something like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-auto order-md-12">
read more here
</div>
<div class="col-md-auto order-md-1">
tags here
</div>
</div>
```

This will render read more and tags next to each other on medium and larger displays, and order read more at the very end.

On smaller displays, cols are full width with read more positioned before the tags.

I copied your example where I applied it.

It is not perfect, but getting there. I would advise you however to look at what elements you use. Tags have meaning in HTML; divs are pretty much meaningless. For links, use the `<a>`-element, not an onclick handler, for lists use `<ul><li>`; and definitely use `<divs>` with `<p>`'s wrapped in it per tag. If you want to take the easy route, a simple list of `<a>`'s would probably be sufficient for the tags.

```css
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@430&display=swap');

        .main {
            max-width: 1200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .read-more p a span:hover {
            color: #0085a1;
        }

        .title-text:hover {
            color: #337ab7;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .title-text {
            font-family: 'Lato';
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: #404040;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .tag p span:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            border-radius: 4px;
        }

        .date {
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #707070;
            margin-left: 15px;
            font-family: 'Work Sans';
        }

        .read {
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #707070;
            margin-left: 7px;
            font-family: 'Work Sans';
        }

        .author {
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #707070;
            margin-left: 7px;
            font-family: 'Work Sans';
        }

        .desc p {
            font-size: 17px;
            font-family: 'Work Sans'
        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3e34c14145.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="main" style="padding-top: 3%; padding-bottom: 5%;">
        <div class="blog-card">
            <div class="row" style="background-color: #fff; padding-top: 1%;">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="https://mlthon.pythonanywhere.com/media/guides/img/carbon_2.png"
                        style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; border-radius: 7px; padding-bottom: 3%;">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <a href="/article/Loading-Really-Large-Datasets-Efficiently-With-Generators-Pytorch-and-TensorFlow"
                        style="text-decoration: none;">
                        <h1 class="title-text">Loading Really Large Datasets Efficiently With Generators (Pytorch &amp;
                            TensorFlow)</h1>
                    </a>

                    <div class="post-meta" style="text-align: center;">
                        <div class="row">
                            <p class="date">&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-calendar-week" aria-hidden="true"></i> Posted On
                                May 5, 2022&nbsp;|</p>
                            <p class="read">&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-clock" aria-hidden="true"></i><span
                                    class="span_read">&nbsp;10 minutes</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="desc">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo sunt tempora dolor laudantium
                            sed optio, explicabo ad deleniti impedit facilis fugit recusandae! Illo, aliquid, dicta
                            beatae quia porro id est.</p>
                    </div>

                  
                   <div class="row" style="">
                    <div class="col-md-4 order-md-12">
                <div class="read-more" style="float: right;">
                    <p style="font-family: 'Open Sans'; font-weight: 700; font-size: 18px;"><a href="/article/Loading-Really-Large-Datasets-Efficiently-With-Generators-Pytorch-and-TensorFlow" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;"><span>[Read
                                More]</span></a></p>
                </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 order-md-1">
<div class="col row">                        <p style="font-family: 'Open Sans'; font-size: 1rem">Tags:</p>

                    <!-- THIS IS WHERE PROBLEM STARTS -->

                    <div class="tag">
                        <p style="font-family: 'Dosis'; font-size: 1rem; color: #008AFF; cursor: pointer;" onclick="tag('deep-learning')">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>#deep-learning</span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tag">
                        <p style="font-family: 'Dosis'; font-size: 1rem; color: #008AFF; cursor: pointer;" onclick="tag('data')">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>#data</span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tag">
                        <p style="font-family: 'Dosis'; font-size: 1rem; color: #008AFF; cursor: pointer;" onclick="tag('pytorch')">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>#pytorch</span></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tag">
                        <p style="font-family: 'Dosis'; font-size: 1rem; color: #008AFF; cursor: pointer;" onclick="tag('tensorflow')">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;<span>#tensorflow</span></p>
                    </div>

                    </div>
</div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```